# Strengthening an implication of the abc conjecture

Tags: nt.number-theory, abc-conjecture

Granville [gives](http://www.dms.umontreal.ca/~andrew/PDF/polysq3.pdf) p.5
an implication of the abc conjecture:

Assume the abc conjecture.
Let $f(x,y)$ be squarefree homogeneous polynomial with integer
coefficients. For coprime integers $m,n$ if $q^2 \mid f(m,n)$
then $q \ll \max(|m|,|n|)^{2+\epsilon}$.

> Can we strengthen this to $q \ll |mn|^{1+\epsilon}$?

For constant $n$ this is consistent with the paper.

Are there heuristic arguments for small roots modulo squares?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes. Without loss of generality, $x$ and $y$ divide $f(x,y)$. (If not, then  multiply by one or the other, and $q$ will still divide it).

Without loss of generality $m \geq n$. Then we know that the product of primes dividing $f(m,n)$ is at least $m^{\deg f - 2 - \epsilon}$ and that $f(m,n)$ is at most a constant times $m^{\deg f -1} n$, so $q$ is at most the ratio, which is $ (mn)^{1+\epsilon}$.